# Avoid infinite loop with useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am trying to display an updated list of items every time a new item is added using the form. Using the useEffect hook I keep getting stuck in an infinite loop that crashes the page.
I am not sure how to add some sort of validation that ask to re-render my component only if a new item has been added.

```
@app.route('/assets')
def get_assets():
  print('this is a test')
  cursor = assets.find() 
  list_cur = list(cursor)
  assets = dumps(list_cur)
  return assets
```

---

```
 function Assets() {
  const [currentAsset, setCurrentAsset] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const result = await fetch('/assets')
      const data = await result.json()
      setCurrentAsset(data)
    })()
  }, [currentAsset]);
 
 
  return (
    <div>
      <header>
      <table className="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Ip Address</th>
            <th>Asset Type</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Notes</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {Object.values(currentAsset).map((item, index) => (
          <tr key={item._id? item._id.$oid: null}>
            <td>{item.ip_address}</td>
            <td>{item.asset_type}</td>
            <td>{item.username}</td>
            <td>{item.notes}</td>
          </tr>
          )
        )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      </header>
    </div>
  );

}

export default Assets;
```

NOTE: I would like to renders updating data without reloading the page every time a new item has been added. I am trying to achieve the same result as this demo: https://taniarascia.github.io/react-hooks/
Is there a Hooks only approach to this?

Comment: This doesn't make sense, you don't add assets in the front end, you fetch them from the back end. How is the front end going to know when a new asset is available?

Comment: what do you mean? I am trying to see the updated list without the need to refresh the browser. Trying to achieve the same result as this: https://taniarascia.github.io/react-hooks/

Answer (score 1):

Inside the “useEffect”, it will update the state “currentAsset”. Then it will trigger the component to re-render again.
As a result, “useEffect()” will run again and update the state. Next, the whole process repeats again, and you're trapped inside an infinite loop.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const result = await fetch('/assets')
      const data = await result.json()
      setCurrentAsset(data)
    })()
  }, []);
```

Comment: this will only fetch the results once and I will need to reload the page to see the updated list

Comment: use setInterval if you want to fetch data on a time base, or if you want to fetch on prop change then pass prop in an empty array of useEffect[

Answer (score 0):

You can't update `state variable` that in the dependancies for `useEffect` inside it
you can make multiple `useEffects`
you should retrieve it first in empty `useEffect` then make another one to listen on `currentAsset` change

```
useEffect(() => {
    /// this will work as componentDidMount 
   // will be called only once at the first after rendering the component
    (async () => {
     const result = await fetch('/assets')
     const data = await result.json()
     setCurrentAsset(data)
   })()
 }, []);

 useEffect(() => {
    // listen on the change of the currentAsset here but DONOT update it here
 }, [currentAsset]);
```

Comment: this won't update the list until I reload the page.

Comment: yes it will, you should specify when the list should update or depend on which var but you shouldn't depend on the one you are updating inside the useeffect

Answer (score 0):

Usually, queries make items change, we should listen changes of query, and update items. just add a query state to make logic clear.

```
function Assets() {
  const [currentAsset, setCurrentAsset] = useState({});
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const result = await fetch('/assets?query=' + query)
      const data = await result.json()
      setCurrentAsset(data)
    })()
  }, [query]);
 
  return (
    <div>
      <header>
      <table className="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Ip Address</th>
            <th>Asset Type</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Notes</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {Object.values(currentAsset).map((item, index) => (
          <tr key={item._id? item._id.$oid: null}>
            <td>{item.ip_address}</td>
            <td>{item.asset_type}</td>
            <td>{item.username}</td>
            <td>{item.notes}</td>
          </tr>
          )
        )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      </header>
    </div>
  );

}

export default Assets;
```